# How will the charges redistribute when a conductor is in contact with a uniformly charged material?

Tags: electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

This is a conceptual question but it is just a bit tricky, Under the influence of E-field any charges that accumulates within the conductor redistributes to the surface.

So when an uncharged spherical shell conductor of certain thickness encloses a charge $q$, a charge of $-q$ will accumulate on the inner surface while a charge $+q$ will accumulate outside the surface of the shell.

What if we made the thickness of the shell larger such that $q$ now comes in contact with the inner surface of the shell, how will now charges get redistributed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any charge that touches the inner surface will flow to the outer surface.

Comment: The material was uniformly charged $+q$.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter how the charge was originally distributed.
Any charge that touches the inner surface will flow to the outer surface where it will be uniformly distributed if the outer surface is spherical.